# Filling form fields with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

So I have a form that will be used for both inserting and editing data from MySQL.
I thought that instead of writing two forms, I'd write just one, that will be used for both purposes. So when it's for inserting new data, its fields (inputs etc) are obsiously empty. But when it's for editing existing data, I have Jquery for filling the fields with .val().

Like this:

```
function formSetup(form_name, array_fields)
{
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var selector;
        for(var key in array_fields)
        {
            selector = "form[name=" + form_name + "] [name=" + key + "]";
            //alert(selector);
            $(selector).val(array_fields[key]);
        }
    });
}
```

And then:

```
var fieldsArray = new Array();
fieldsArray["field1"] = "data read from Myqsl php";
fieldsArray["field2"] = "data read from Myqsl php";
//etc
```

Btw, PHP does the job of telling my page whether this form is supposed to insert or edit data, so this javascript function will only be called by php when there is $_GET["action"]=="edit".

What I want to know is, is this the best approach for doing that kind of thing?
Is there a standard way for doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You are right, it is nice to have only one form.
Values usualyy filled on the server side (by PHP in your case) but this depends on the project architecture - you may use jQuery. Example for PHP:

```
<input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="<?=$data['email']?:''?>" />
```

Example with jQuery:

```
$.get("getData.php", function(data){
  $("input#id").val(data['id']);
  $("input#email").val(data['email']);
});
```

To find out whether the form is used to insert or update data use hidden field with the database record's primary key (usually `id`):

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" id="id" value="<?=$data['id']?:''?>" />
```

When this field is empty - create a new record. When it is containing some value - update a record having the primary key containing in it.

Comment: Using php code on each 'value' makes my code look very ugly. And what about <selects>? I'll have to check each select with php? I think it's better to use jquery

Comment: Select's options are filled inside the loop, but yes, you should check default value and user values. As to the ugly code - your code becomes simpler as you don't have to create additional data sets for jQuery. When the code is simpler, it is easier to maintain it. And if you use one of popular frameworks - most of them allow semi-automatic forms generation/population.

Answer (score 0):

Me to. I'm making the same form for two actions - inserting and editing.
If you using some kind of ajax technology and trying to fill up the form without page refresh you are going right way. But better is just to add values with php by echo'ing data in to the fields values.
There is no such standards for that. Accept you.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this serverside.

In raw PHP, that is one without a support framework like Yii, Cake, etc. I would implement a light weight MVC framework.

Create a Business Object class.

```
class MyData
{
  $field1;
  $field2;
  ..
}
```

Then fill your Business Object from your datasource.

```
 $data = new MyData();
 $data->field1 = "Something";
 $data->field2 = "Other stuff...";
```

or if it's new data.

```
$data = new MyData();
```

Create a form template.
Contents of form.tmp.php

```
<form ...>
  <input type="text" name="field1" value="<?= $data->field1; ?>" />
  <input type="text" name="field2" value="<?= $data->field2; ?>" />
</form>
```

Then use a light wrapper around your template.

```
ob_start();
  include('form.tmp.php');

$html = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
```

It's been a while since I've done anything like this.  There are a TON of PHP frameworks that take care of this for you though.  Some lightweight ones, some heavy enterprise ones.

I didn't test this, but this should get you started.

Answer (score 0):

> Instead of populating your form with javascript the better approach would be to handle this server side.

In your php template you can do populate the inputs like this

```
<input name="field1" type="text" value="<?php echo $fieldValues['field1']; ?>" />
<input name="field2" type="text" value="<?php echo $fieldValues['field2']; ?>" />
```

If there is no value for each variable the field will be blank otherwise the data you retrieved from the database will be inserted.